# Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a function that is differntiable $n+1$ times for some positive integer $n$...

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a function that is differntiable $n+1$ times for some positive integer $n$. The $i$-th derivative of $f$ is denoted by $f^{(i)}$. Suppose $$f(1)=f(0)=f^{(1)}(0)=\ldots=f^{(n)}(0)=0$$
Prove that $f^{(n+1)}(x)=0$ for some $x\in (0,1)$

I realise that $0$ is a multiple root of $f(x)$ with multiplicity $n$ and also I have to apply Rolles' Theorem to solve this problem. But, I really cannot figure out how. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's just show the twice differentiable case. So we know $f(0) = f'(0) = f(1) = 0$.

By the Mean Value Theorem, there is some $c \in (0,1)$ so that $f'(c) = 0$. Now we consider the problem again, noting that $f'(0) = f'(c) = 0$. By the Mean Value Theorem, there is some $d \in (0, c)$ such that $f''(d) = 0$.

The general case follows immediately from induction. $\diamondsuit$

As an aside, this is morally equivalent to Taylor's Theorem (in the same way that the ordinary Mean Value Theorem is equivalent to the degree one expansion with second degree error term form of Taylor's Theorem).

Comment: Oh yes!! you are so correct! I just tried to do something like this and couldn't. Thank you very much.

Comment: But I don't know Taylor's Theorem. I am trying to learn that.